# How do I stop the error log view showing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How do I stop the error log view showing in eclipse everytime there's an error?

Comment: Im using Galilieo, but imagine it would be similar for most versions

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In the dropdown menu (small triangle on the top - right of the view), deselect "Activate on new events"

Comment: I offer you my love forever for sharing this. Thank you so much. <3

Answer (score 15):

Click the little triangle in the top right, then untick 'Activate on new events'.

Comment: 39 seconds too slow. Dang.