# Seeing only System.out in eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, console, system.out

When I Get system errors they are taking up all of the console. How do I see system.out that I made before these errors happened?

Answer (score 0):

"In the dropdown menu (small triangle on the top - right of the view), deselect 'Activate on new events'"

[How do I stop the error log view showing in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300697/how-do-i-stop-the-error-log-view-showing-in-eclipse)

Could I help? ;)

Comment: is it on console tab toolbar? there are two drop downs. "display selected console" and "open console"